# Eclipse Configuration Problems

Tags: eclipse, configuration, package-managers

Lately, I am trying to use Eclipse more often, but so far I have shied away from it because I found it so difficult to install new packages. Whenever I find and try to install a new package, the errors panel flashes a batch of configuration errors. It requires this or that package to install this one. And when I find that package, it turns out that package requires another one that I don't have...and it's been a daunting problem for me.

These days I've been running into these configuration errors:

> The current configuration contains errors and this operation can have
>   unpredictable results.
>
> ```
>   JST Web Core Patches requires feature "org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature ".
>   WST Server Core Patches requires feature "org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature".
> ```

Specifically, I'm looking for help to figure out how to get around these errors. (There aren't any informative pages in Google for "org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature.")

More generally, though, I am wondering what alternatives I have to the internal package management system of Eclipse? (If I'm doing it wrong and the internal system is not as difficult as it seems to me, let me know of that as well!) I've heard of Pulse, but haven't used that much.

Comment: What plugin are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

are you using 3.4 Ganymede? .. the dependencies should be figured out and selected for you .. in 3.1 there is a 'Select Required' button in the Updates window which is supposed to locate and select for you all the dependencies